# Blue Yeti Microphone only works if I unplug and replug after boot

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone

The blue yeti handles both input and output, after I re-boot the machine the microphone is detected everything appears normal in software. But no input from the microphone or sound output works until I unplug and replug the cable.

This is a *known* issue with these microphones on all platforms. I dual boot, and the same thing happens on Windows. In Windows, there's a workaround [Discussed here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/in8zo2/blue_yeti_microphone_only_works_after_unplugging/g466ijh/) that involves uninstalling a particular device in device manager. This "fix" is persistent on windows. (I uninstalled the correct device in device manager, and now whenever I boot windows I no longer have to unplug/replug the mic).

This is obviously a very minor issue, but I'd appreciate any help in troubleshooting/replicating the windows fix on Ubuntu.

Edit: I am specifically experiencing the issue on Ubuntu 20.04.5.

Comment: Have you figured out anything about this problem?

Comment: I'm also wondering as this exact thing happens to me. Interesting that Windows experiences the same issue though. that makes me feel a little better at least.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with the way the computer **shuts down**. And the **power cycle to the mic**.

#### reasoning

As for me, I dual boot windows 10 and Arch:

- Whenever my computer shuts down on arch, the mic doesn't work next boot until replugging usb.
- *But when my computer shuts down on windows 10, the mic works properly next boot.*

Also:

- on arch if the computer goes to sleep, when it wakes up, the mic doesn't work again.
- Can't say the same for windows, since it is seldom used.

Can't say I solved that. I keep replugging.